HotkeyP Macros - Escape Sequences
I'm trying to create a HotkeyP macro to paste the following text:
<link rel="canonical" href="">

I then want the cursor to go back up to the just-pasted text, go to the end of the line, then go left two positions. The cursor should end up between the quote marks after href=.
This is what I came up with so far:
<link rel="canonical" href="">%r\up\end\left\left

But when I invoke the macro, the escape sequences are treated as normal text, instead of keystrokes, so the output looks exactly like the macro text.
I'm obviously misunderstanding the help file, but can't see how to fix the problem.
Does anyone know how to use the HotkeyP escape sequences properly?
